# jQuery UI - make div not resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a div that is made resizable using jQuery UI. How can I dynamically make it not resizable anymore?
I tried calling `resizable({ disabled: true })` but the handle still showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops...
I was disabling "resizable" before I enabled it...

Answer (score 5):

Use this code:    .resizable( "destroy" )

Comment: or .resizable( "disable" ) but this is like you already tried

Answer (score 3):

Try `.resizable("option", "disabled", true);`

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#option-disabled

Your solution is not working because, as per the documentation you need use the setter that I mentioned, if you want to disable it after initialization (you code will only work if its an initialization call)